# SVG / CSS - fill different paths with different colours

Tags: html, css, svg, fill

I have a svg with different paths, ellipses etc. They have different fill colours. Say red & blue. Now, I put them all into a sprite, and would now like to modify fill colour with css on hover, so what I would normally do is remove the fills from the svg and do everything with css' `fill` property.

However, since I have different colours here, I cannot simply do `fill:red`, since everything will be red, but I want some of it to be blue.

Comment: For us to help without guessing, we need to see the SVG

Comment: You'll have to script this.

Comment: I have added a snippet (somehow working) to your question. May be now you can clarify your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a different class to each of the paths:

```
<circle  class="circleClass" cx="40" cy="50" r="26"/>
<square  class="squareClass"   cx="40" cy="50" r="26"/>
```

Then target those classes in your CSS:

```
.circleClass {
  fill: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I am wondering though how to do hovers. `.circleClass:hover` does not seem to work. I have also tried `.icon:hover .circleClass {...`, (where icon is the class of the svg, not a class within the svg) but this also does not seem to work.

Comment: You'll need to post a minimal example of your current code for anyone to be able to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to every path or you can use the nth-child.

Here is an easy example:

```
<path bla-bla-bla>
<path bla-bla-bla>
<path bla-bla-bla>

path:nth-child(1){
   fill:red;
}

path:nth-child(2){
   fill:blue;
}

path:nth-child(3){
   fill:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing can't work.  Anything referenced via a `<use>` is not present in the DOM under the `<use>` element.

```
.icon:hover .outer { }
```

won't work because the path with class `outer` is not a descendant of `.icon`.  If you want to style the contents of a symbol, you need to do it by applying the ruules directly to the symbol. For example:

```
#btn-tester .outer { }
```

Unfortunately `:hover` events don't apply to symbols. So you can't do:

```
#btn-tester:hover .outer { }
```

Even if that worked, you may not want to do that anyway. If there were any other uses of the symbol on the page, it would change them also.

You probably are going to have to just inline the SVG on the page where you want it.  Instead of using a symbol.